# How to use Managed or Enterprise connector on Azure Logic App Standard plan?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I am unable to find any Managed or enterprise connector on **Logic App Standard plan**.I see only builtin connector for Azure Logic App Standard plan.

Is there any guideline or limitation documentation available that can explain how to use the standard or enteprise connector in Azure Logic App Standard plan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that there are limitation on what connectors one can use on Azure Logic App Standard plan stateful and stateless workflow.

Only builtin connectors are available in stateless Azure Logic App based on standard plan.

Azure logic app based on standard plan can show managed connectors (with limitations) on Azure Tab for stateful workdlow only.